# Error triggering a Link hook using react-router-v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm updating a sourcecode from react-router-5 to version 6. So far I'm getting this error:

```
Error: [div] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

The bug is triggered when I activate a link in this component(QuoteItem.js):

```
const QuoteItem = (props) => { 
  return (
    <li className={classes.item}>
      <figure>
        <blockquote>
          <p>{props.text}</p>
        </blockquote>
        <figcaption>{props.author}</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div className={classes.item}>
          <Link className='btn' to={`/quotes/${props.id}`}>View Fullscreen</Link>
        </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

in another component (VerQuotes) I defined the routes:

```
const VerQuotes = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <Layout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="quotes" element={<AllQuotes />} />

            <Route path="new-quote" element={<NewQuote />} />

            <Route path="quotes/:quoteId" element={<QuoteDetail />} />
          </Routes>
        </Layout>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm kind of lost how to tackle the error, your comments will be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

### Update

QuoteDetail

```
const QuoteDetail = () => {
  const match = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();
  const { quoteId } = params;


  const { sendRequest, status, data: loadedQuote, error } = useHttp(getSingleQuote, true);

  //const quote = DUMMY_NOTES.find((quote) => quote.id === params.quoteId);
  useEffect(() => {
    sendRequest(quoteId);
  }, [sendRequest, quoteId]);

  if(status === "pending"){
    return (
      <div className="centered">
        <LoadingSpinner />
      </div>
    );
  }

  if(error){
    return <p className="centered">{error}</p>;
  }

  if (!loadedQuote.text) {
    return <p>No Quote Found!</p>;
  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <HighlightedQuote text={loadedQuote.text} author={loadedQuote.author} />
      <Routes>
      <Route path={match}>
        <div className="centered">
          <Link
            className="btn--flat"
            to={`${match}/comments`}
          >
            Load Comments
          </Link>
        </div>
      </Route>
      <Route path={`${match}/comments`} element={<Comments />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is `QuoteDetail` rendering more route components? All `Route` components must be rendered by a `Routes` or another `Route` component in the case of nesting routes, and `Routes` can only render `Route` or `React.Fragment` components.

Comment: yes, QuoteDetail is rendering another route. Based on your comment, shall I use Routes and then use Link hook inside of it?

Comment: The `Link` components need only have a router somewhere above them in the ReactTree. Any `Route` components, however, need to be rendered by a `Routes` or `Route` component. Can you update your question to include the `QuoteDetail` component?

Comment: hi @DrewReese, the above component is VerQuotes, that one has all the routes

Comment: Thanks for update. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: sure @DrewReese, I'll let you know when the codesandbox is ready, if you have any suggestions about what online service is better let me know

Comment: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) works well. It works really well if you are already familiar with Vscode as it is effectively a Vscode clone that runs in the browser.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, this is the link to the sandox: https://codesandbox.io/live/8e2a90116fb  .  The target componets are VerQuotes.js and QuoteItem.js, the last one is in this path: components/Quotes/components/. Press "all quotes" and then press "View fullscreen" to generate the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

After tracing your code I found you had a couple issues in `QuoteDetail` component.

1. You used `const match = useNavigate();` (*so `match` is really the `navigate` function*) but then later used `match` to attempt to form a `path` string for a `Route`.
2. The `Route` component's `children` prop is only for rendering nested routes. The error you see is the use of the `div` element that isn't a `Route` component.

Code

```
<Routes>
  <Route path={match}>
    <div className="centered">
      <Link
        className="btn--flat"
        to={`${match}/comments`}
      >
        Load Comments
      </Link>
    </div>
  </Route>
  <Route path={`${match}/comments`} element={<Comments />}></Route>
</Routes>
```

## Solution

Remove `const match = useNavigate();` since it is not used, and place the `div` into the `element` prop of the `Route`. Change the `path` props to use relative routing from the current route path that's already been built up.

```
const QuoteDetail = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const { quoteId } = params;

  const { sendRequest, status, data: loadedQuote, error } = useHttp(
    getSingleQuote,
    true
  );

  //const quote = DUMMY_NOTES.find((quote) => quote.id === params.quoteId);
  useEffect(() => {
    sendRequest(quoteId);
  }, [sendRequest, quoteId]);

  if (status === "pending") {
    return (
      <div className="centered">
        <LoadingSpinner />
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (error) {
    return <p className="centered">{error}</p>;
  }

  if (!loadedQuote.text) {
    return <p>No Quote Found!</p>;
  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <HighlightedQuote text={loadedQuote.text} author={loadedQuote.author} />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <div className="centered">
              <Link className="btn--flat" to="comments">
                Load Comments
              </Link>
            </div>
          }
        />
        <Route path="comments" element={<Comments />} />
      </Routes>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit error-triggering-a-link-hook-using-react-router-v6]

Comment: thank you so much @DrewReese, it works like a charm; without your help I couldn't make it, I was so focused on other components and totally forgot I have another routes on QuoteDetails. I have to say it was my first time using react-router-v6, thanks for all your support. Best wishes

Comment: @htamayo Welcome. Yeah... after looking at your code I had flashbacks to my first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70901984/error-triggering-a-link-hook-using-react-router-v6#comment125342812_70901984) and was almost spot on. Glad to help. Cheers and good luck!